# Visual Studio 2017 Creating/Debugging Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 from 2015. I am taking a computing 2 course in college currently and last year when I used 2015 in computing 1 I'd create my projects by doing

New Project > C++ > Win32 Project > Checked "Empty Project" > Unchecked "SDL" > Then creating a main.c file

Now on 2017 I create a project by doing

New Project > C++ > Empty Project > Then creating a main.c file

Now on 2017 when I attempted to run a simple program by going to "Start without debugging" a terminal pops up really quick and then disappears right away without letting me see my program run.

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 1, i;

for (i = 0; i != 10; i++)
{
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, x);
}

return 0;
}
```

So my question is, How do I set up my projects in Visual Studios 2017 so that I can complete HW for my computing 2 class?

Comment: I don't know about this breaking change in behavior of VS (previous versions asked you to press a key when you ran without debug). I don't use 2017 yet. With that said you can always put a breakpoint at the return and debug. Or run you program directly from the command line (open a cmd.exe instance and change directory to the folder containing your exe and type its name.)

Comment: You can add `system("pause");` before return to enforce this behavior. Though running under debugger with breakpoint at return seem to be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

When you run C++ applications from Visual Studio they behave differently depending on a project setting (right click on project > Configuration Properties > System > Subsystem). For a console project /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE when the program ends, the console stays open and waits for you to press a key, allowing you to see the output. For other project types it closes.

So, to be able to view the results either create your project as a Win32 Console application OR if you already created it as an Empty project, then change the Subsystem property to Console.